# ListView within DialogFragment will not keep up to date

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, back-stack

I'm having a really annoying problem with DialogFragments and backstacks.

I have a MainActivity that hosts an ActiveMenuFragment.

ActiveMenuFragment has a button that launches a DialogFragmentActionSelector (All methods are run from MainActivity forced interface methods):

```
  /**
    * Opens the action selection dialog, so the user may pick an action to
    * begin.
    */
   @Override
   public void openActionSelector() {
      actionSelectorFragment = DialogFragmentActionSelector.newInstance();
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      args.putSerializable("Profile", currentProfile);
      actionSelectorFragment.setArguments(args);
      FragmentTransaction ft = this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
      ft.addToBackStack("Action Selector");
      actionSelectorFragment.show(ft, "Action Selector");
   }
```

This fragment displays a ListView with the list of actions. Everything is fine at this point. Even previously added new actions will show up here. Now, if the user wants to define a new action, they press a button in the DialogFragment that launches DialogFragmentDefineNewAction:

```
/**
    * Opens the action selection dialog, so the user may pick an action to
    * begin.
    */
   @Override
   public void openActionSelector() {
      actionSelectorFragment = DialogFragmentActionSelector.newInstance();
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      args.putSerializable("Profile", currentProfile);
      actionSelectorFragment.setArguments(args);
      FragmentTransaction ft = this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
      ft.addToBackStack("Action Selector");
      actionSelectorFragment.show(ft, "Action Selector");
   }
```

After user has entered in their new action's data, they hit the confirm button, which is SUPPOSED to update the ListView within the previous fragment (DialogFragmenActionSelector), but does not. It shows the same old 8 actions every time I return to it via the backstack.

```
   /**
    * Takes the action defined in the DefineNewAction fragment and adds it to
    * the user dictionary.
    */
   @Override
   public void addNewActionToDictionary(Action toAdd) {
      currentProfile.getDictionary().addDefinition(toAdd);
      actionSelectorFragment.updateProfile(currentProfile);
   }
```

For reference, here is the entire DialogFragmentActionSelector, with its ArrayAdapter included:

```
public class DialogFragmentActionSelector extends DialogFragment implements
      OnClickListener {

   private EditText searchBar;
   private Button defineNewActionBtn;
   private ListView actionList;
   private UserProfile user;
   private ListViewInterface mInterface;
   private ActionsAdapter adapter;

   public interface ListViewInterface {

      void openDefineNewAction();



      void setActiveMenuActionBar(String action);
   }



   public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
      super.onAttach(activity);
      if (activity instanceof ListViewInterface) {
         mInterface = (ListViewInterface) activity;
      } else {
         throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
               + " must implement ListViewInterface");
      }
   }



   /**
    * Constructor for the fragment.
    * 
    * @return
    */
   public static DialogFragmentActionSelector newInstance() {
      DialogFragmentActionSelector dfm = new DialogFragmentActionSelector();
      return dfm;
   }



   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View toReturn = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_action_selector_layout, container, false);
      user = (UserProfile) this.getArguments().get("Profile");
      searchBar = (EditText) toReturn.findViewById(R.id.action_search_bar);
      searchBar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

         @Override
         public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
         }



         @Override
         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
               int arg3) {
         }



         @Override
         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
               int arg3) {
            adapter.updateList();
            adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0);
         }
      });
      defineNewActionBtn = (Button) toReturn
            .findViewById(R.id.define_new_action);
      defineNewActionBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
      actionList = (ListView) toReturn.findViewById(R.id.actions_list);
      ArrayList<Action> allActions = user.getDictionary().getAllActions();
      adapter = new ActionsAdapter(this.getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, allActions, inflater);
      actionList.setAdapter(adapter);
      actionList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View clickedView,
               int index, long id) {
            Action selectedAction = (Action) parent.getItemAtPosition(index);
            mInterface.setActiveMenuActionBar(selectedAction.getActionName());
            dismiss();
         }
      });
      return toReturn;
   }



   public void updateProfile(UserProfile updatedProfile) {
      user = updatedProfile;
      ArrayList<Action> allActions = user.getDictionary().getAllActions();
      adapter = new ActionsAdapter(this.getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, allActions, getActivity()
                  .getLayoutInflater());
      actionList.setAdapter(adapter);
      actionList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View clickedView,
               int index, long id) {
            Action selectedAction = (Action) parent.getItemAtPosition(index);
            mInterface.setActiveMenuActionBar(selectedAction.getActionName());
            dismiss();
         }
      });
      // this.updateListView();
   }



   private void updateListView() {
      adapter.updateList();
   }

   // TODO FIX CONSTRUCTOR. UPON RETURNING, IT REVERTS TO DEFAULT 8 ACTIONS
   // RATHER THAN NEW ONES.
   private class ActionsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Action> implements
         Filterable {

      LayoutInflater inflater;
      ArrayList<Action> actionsList;



      public ActionsAdapter(Context context, int resId,
            ArrayList<Action> objects, LayoutInflater inflater) {
         super(context, resId, objects);
         this.actionsList = objects;
         this.inflater = inflater;
      }



      @Override
      public int getCount() {
         return actionsList.size();
      }



      @Override
      public Action getItem(int position) {
         return actionsList.get(position);
      }



      @Override
      public long getItemId(int position) {
         return this.getItem(position).hashCode();
      }



      public void updateList() {
         ArrayList<Action> allActions = user.getDictionary().getAllActions();
         actionsList = allActions;
         notifyDataSetInvalidated();
         // notifyDataSetChanged();
      }



      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         ViewHolder holder = null;
         Action toWrap = actionsList.get(position);
         if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(
                  R.layout.listview_row_action_selector, parent, false);
            holder.actionName = (TextView) convertView
                  .findViewById(R.id.action_title);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
         } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
         holder.actionName.setText(toWrap.getActionName());
         return convertView;
      }

      private class ViewHolder {

         TextView actionName;
      }



      /**
       * Filters the adapter's database.
       */
      @Override
      public Filter getFilter() {
         Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
               FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
               ArrayList<Action> matchingActions = new ArrayList<Action>();
               for (int i = 0; i < actionsList.size(); i++) {
                  Action actionToCheck = actionsList.get(i);
                  ArrayList<String> actionTags = actionToCheck.getTags();
                  String searchQuery = constraint.toString();
                  boolean foundMatch = false;
                  int k = 0;
                  int tagSize = actionTags.size();
                  if (tagSize != 0) {
                     while (!foundMatch && k < tagSize) {
                        if (actionTags.get(k).contains(searchQuery)) {
                           matchingActions.add(actionToCheck);
                           foundMatch = true;
                        }
                        k++;
                     }
                  }
               }
               results.count = matchingActions.size();
               results.values = matchingActions;
               return results;
            }



            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                  FilterResults results) {
               // actionsList.clear();
               actionsList = (ArrayList<Action>) results.values;
               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
         };
         return filter;
      }
   }



   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.define_new_action:
         mInterface.openDefineNewAction();
         break;
      default:
         break;
      }
   }



   public void addNewActionToDictionary(Action toAdd) {
      user.getDictionary().addDefinition(toAdd);
      adapter.add(toAdd);
      adapter.updateList();
   }
}
```

Am I supposed to use notifyDataSetChanged() or invalidated? Because it isn't working on my adapter.

If I close all the dialogs and open them up again, the updated actions are shown in the listview. Why?

Also, I feel as though I am doing things inefficiently and making things more complicated than they need to be. A UserProfile object also holds the Actions Dictionary and other information that pertains to the user. Should the host activity hold on to this and modify it, or should the ActiveMenu fragment handle it?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have added the new item to the adapter you have to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` so that the listview refreshes itself with the new set of data found in the adapter. You need not change the adapter itself as you are doing in the function `updateProfile`

Comment: I've tried calling that from addNewActionToDictionary(Action toAdd). The userprofile is updated from the activity level and from within the ActiveMenuFragment, and ActionSelectorDialogFragment. When the DialogFragment is popped off the stack upon returning, however, it's all still the same. Are you sure it's not the backstack that's causing me problems? Perhaps I should recreate the DialogFragment instead.

Comment: UPDATE: I added some LogCat lines into my adapter every time it got re/created from within the fragment. It turns out that the underlying data is there, BUT it's not showing in the ListView.

Comment: If the adapter has the items in it, then the items will be displayed for sure. When your Fragment comes to focus (after the back key press) could you check the what is the cound of the Adapter. If it has the newly added items as well. The last resort is the force listview draw using the call invalidate()

Comment: It indeed is in there. After the back press, it reported my new action in the adapter, but it still isn't being rendered in the listview. I feel like I have to find a way to force it to invalidate/notify, but only AFTER the DialogFragment has returned from the backstack.

Comment: I added a debug button to the DialogFragment that would manually do the force update via notifyDataSetChanged(). That seems to do the trick. How can I implement this manually though? I have to check to see if the fragment has come on screen, and if it is, force it to update.

Comment: When your Fragment comes to foreground one of the fragment lifecycle methods will be called. For example, onResume or onStart. You can refresh the Fragment there.

Comment: (Wait, nevermind. onResume is being called. I was testing the activity, not the fragment. Still though, I forced update within onResume, to no avail.) According to the documentation, when something is popped off the backstack, its operations between beginTransaction and commit/show are reversed. What does that tell me?

Comment: I did a little more digging. The DialogFragment does not actually show itself until onResume has finished calling. I have to find some place to force the update AFTER onResume, but that's the last call there is before it becomes visible!